# Determining Build Flavor when running gradlew build from command line

Tags: gradle, gradlew, android-productflavors

Popular way to determine flavor in Gradle script is to parse the return of:

```
gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests().toString()
```

This works for me when building from Android Studio but for some reason, this fails when running `gradlew build` from command line.

What gets returned from `getTaskRequests()` instead is:

```
[DefaultTaskExecutionRequest{args=[build],projectPath='null'}]
```

How can I make this work from command line?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have to call `toString()` at the end of:

```
gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskRequests()
```

If skipped you'll get a `List<TaskExecutionRequest>` as in the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#getTaskRequests--), instead of an instance of `String`.

Comment: I didn't paste all the code in the examples using getTaskRequests() but they all use toString so that a pattern match can be used to determine the "flavor".  The point of my question is that getTaskRequests() is not returning a List of "tasks" containing the current flavor as it does when run from within Android Studio.